Enable features in Power Shell not work
I'm trying to create a site template in Project web app, but I get the error that a feature is disabled
"This web model requires certain features to be installed, activated, and licensed. The following issues are blocking the application of the template:
Feature Description
Site Collection Resource Scope
Resource ID 3bc0c1e1-b7d5-4e82-afd7-9f7e59b60416
Issue Not Enabled
This template cannot be used for this site collection until the above issues are resolved. “
Microsoft advised using this script:
*> Install-Module -Name Microsofoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell

Connect-SPOService -url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Install-Module -Name SharePointPNPPowerShellOnline -Force
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa**

So far everything has gone well, but the next command has shown an error:
Get-PnpFeature
Get-PnpFeature: Remote server returned an error (404) Not found
In other cases, it also does not recognize this command
Get-PnpFeature: The term 'Get-PnpFeature' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program name. Check the spelling of the name or, if a path
has been included, see if the path is correct and try again.
How do I enable a Pnp Feature in PowerShell, does anyone know?

The error message means that the PnP Module cmdlets are not available. Something went wrong with the module installation or import.
Check, if it's available:
Get-module

PnP.Powershell should be listed there. As long as it's not, it doesn't make sense to try Enable-PnPFeature
If the installation was fine and without errors, run Import-Module PnP.Powershell. Check afterwards if the module is available with Get-Module.
If the module is available but you are still getting The term 'Get-PnpFeature' is not recognized as a cmdlet (which would be very weird), run Get-Command, check if the cmdlets are there and if the module is the correct version.
And finally to your question: How do I enable a Pnp Feature in PowerShell
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe -Force

Make sure you adjust the ID of your feature!
